# Использование масок (wildcards) при работе с дженериками типобезопасно?

Tags: java, generics, syntax, wildcards

Например, первая строка аналогична второй в плане типобезопасность?

```
Solution<?> object = new Solution<Integer>(); // 1
Solution object = new Solution<Integer>(); // 2
```

Или же компилятор при работе с переменной `object`, будет воспринимать её тип как `Solution<Integer>`?

Answer (score 1):

Не аналогична. Использованием `<?>` вы явно указываете компилятору, что не знаете какой тип будет храниться в `Solution`.